# Complicated SQL query - how do i do it?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm currently working on a small feature for a project and wondered how best to achieve the result, i have a table full of reviews with the score being out of 5 and being stored as score in the database, on one page i want to show how many of each score reviews there are, ie number of 5 star reviews, 4 star etc

But i don't know how best to achieve surely i don't need 5 different queries, that would be awful design would it not ?

Thanks and hope you can help !

Comment: Share your table structures and we can help you better

Comment: Can you provide the table name, a list of its columns including datatype and 3 lines of sample data?

Comment: Kind of *GROUP BY* might help, though question need clarification and more details like tables structure with relationships to find out the possible complexity of the query(ies).

Comment: Unfair advertising — you promised a *complicated* query!

Comment: sorry about that - i just assumed it would have been more complicated :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since I do not have your table structure, I would do something similar to this (with appropriate names replaced)

**edited SQL based on comments**

```
Select Score, COUNT (*) as NumScores
From MyTableOfScores
Group By Score
Order by Score Desc
```

Comment: Maybe you would like `Order by Score DESC`

Comment: worked perfectly - thanks very very much - couldn't have done it without you :)

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this:

```
select score, count(*) from reviews group by score
```